# Quick look doesn't work in spotlight

Tags: spotlight, preview, quicklook

When I use spotlight (on Yosemite 10.10.2), Quick Look doesn't display a preview in the right panel anymore. Only when I click on a folder in the left panel it displays the contents of the map in the right panel. But when I click on either a .pdf or a .pages file in the left panel, the right panel is empty, whereas a few weeks ago it still *did* display a preview in the right panel in those cases.

Comment: Do you have "Show Preview" or "Hide Preview" in the View menu when Finder is in the foreground? You can turn the Preview off and on with SHIFT + CMD + P.

Comment: When I am in the Finder search window, I can turn the Preview off and on using the SHIFT+CMD+P. Yet when I am in the Spotlight window, I cannot. The view menu displays "Show Preview" in grey letters in that case, suggesting that it cannot be turned off or on.

I am correct that the Spotlight function should also be able to show previews right?

Comment: Preview only works in column mode.

Comment: Has it always been like that? If I recall correctly, spotlight used to show previews as well. In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you thinking of Spotlight searches launched from the menubar perhaps? Rather than Spotlight searches launched from the Finder.

Comment: I am thinking of the Spotlight searches launched from CMD + SPACE (and thus not from ALT + CMD + SPACE).

Comment: Had this happen to me... This helped: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174462/spotlight-preview-broken-in-yosemite

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "Show Preview" or "Hide Preview" in the View menu when Finder is in the foreground? You can turn the Preview off and on with SHIFT + CMD + P.

However, the preview pane only works in column mode.